# Query to return results WHERE the datetime is under X months

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am working on a JSON API, and one of the input parameters is to specify an integer input defined like this:

```
1 - would return results within one month from today
2 - would return results within three months from today
3 - would return results within six months from today
4 - would return results within one year from today
```

So in essence the API would be used like this:

http://url.com/index.php?route=api/order/all&search_time=1, would return all results from table X within one month from today.

My table has the `datetime` field, so the date issue is not the problem. I know where is a MySQL function that you can retrieve the month like `MONTH(datetime_item)`, so you can use it like `WHERE MONTH(datetime_item) = 8`, but this does not seem relevant to my usage.

So in MySQL pseudo-code, the query would look like this:

`WHERE datetime is within three months ago from today`

Comment: check this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Comment: @lolka_bolka Not sure SO encourages that as a resource (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT * from table_name where datetime_item >= now()-interval 'x' month
```

*Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL together with the + or - operator:*

```
date + INTERVAL expr unit
date - INTERVAL expr unit
```

[Reference - documentation for date/time functionsDocumentation for date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Seems to work fine for me - if someone wants to clarify why this is downvoted.. Feel free.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I am glad to hear it worked for you.